# Convertir un html a pdf

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, angularjs, pdf

En el momento desarrollo un `app` web donde tengo que generar un `pdf` a partir de la información que se tiene en un formulario de `Html` , la cuestión es que dicho formulario estaría oculto, en el momento he buscado información pero se usa `php` lo cual no se me es permitido en el `app` que desarrollo.

Estoy usando `javascript` , `jquery`, `angularjs`, agradezco la información que se me pueda aportar , en el momento no he desarrollado código con respecto a esa conversión, alguna idea ?

Comment: Intenta usar una biblioteca como [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) o similar y, si te encuentras algún problema, escribe una pregunta más específica. Esta publicación es demasiado amplia y basada en opiniones y no se ajusta bien al formato de este sitio.

Comment: En concreto, primero usa [html2canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas) para convertir el formulario a un elemento Canvas y luego usas [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) para convertir ese canvas a PDF, deberás obtener una imagen del canvas, esto es, un screenshot, mediante `canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg')` y pasar este base64 a PDF usando el método `setImage`.

Comment: El principal problema que tienes que dices **que el formulario está oculto**. Si está oculto, el canvas resultará vacío, y si usas `visibility: hidden`, verás bloques negros. La solución es que, al cargar el DOM **conviertas el formualario** e inmediatamente después, lo ocultes. Esto puedes hacerlo gracias al evento `onclone`, que acepta una función; aquí puedes ocultar el nodo. Luego, solo asignar el método `jsPDF#save` a un botón para que guarde el documento. Como plus, agrega un preloader a esa página que sea visible hasta que se haya terminado de convertir el formulario a canvas.

Answer (score -1):

Como te mencionan, JSPDF es una gran opción en caso de que no quieras involucrar backend.
En mi caso tuve que hacer algo similar para una aplicación hecha con Cordova para dispositivos móviles y use un plugin que te puede funcionar a ti también, [PDF-Generator](https://github.com/cesarvr/pdf-generator) de CesarVR quien te da un [ejemplo](https://github.com/cesarvr/pdf-generator-example) básico.